# How thorough should a dental check-up be?

Tags: dentistry

I recently had a dental check-up where I received x-rays. After the hygienist cleaned my teeth and checked gum levels the dentist came in and spent no more than 30 seconds looking at my teeth. This 30 second exam was only visual and there was no probing of my teeth.

I was wondering if the dentist failed to perform part of the check-up or if everything he could possibly catch could be caught from my x-rays and this quick visual examination?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Hygienists are trained to identify problems and they examine every surface of every tooth quite carefully. That in combination with the x-rays means the dentist really doesn't need to spend more than just a few moments. In fact, mostly they're in the room to hear the hygienist's report. Had the hygienist found a problem, they would have told the dentist and I would expect the exam would be longer. What you experienced sounds like every routine cleaning I've ever had.

Comment: Also, be aware that this site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. Questions that do not may be closed. I would imagine there are established guidelines on what constitutes a dental exam, so that would be the thing to look for.